# Can not get siblings from the start of a query xpath

Tags: node.js, xpath

I have the following structure of the XML file:

```
<body>
  <content>
    <text type="header">Header 1</text>
  </content>
  <content>
    <text type="text">Text 1</text>
  </content>
</body>
```

I need to get the first one **content tag** and then using that content element get his **content tag** sibling in node.js with ***select*** function.

Node.js **xpath** npm package.

What I am trying to do is:

> **allDocumentString is a string representation of all the XML
>   file.**

1. const headerContentTag = select('//content/text[@type = 'header']', allDocumentString);
2. const textContentTag = select('//following-sibling::content', headerContentTagString);

But it does not work.

I need to exactly get **the first one content tag** and then depending on that tag **the last one**.
I know I can get the second one tag just without the first one, but I need the first one.

Comment: This gets the text for the first content tag:``"//content[1]/text"`` and you can use last() to get the last. Although I'm not sure what the overall aim is here.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, what you need is :

```
var doc = new dom().parseFromString(xml)
var nodes = xpath.select("//body/content[1][./text[@type='header']]/following-sibling::content[last()]", doc)
```

We first look for the first `content` element, child of body and which contains a `text` element with a `@header` attribute. Then get we get his `last` `following-sibling`.